# Node.js - Redirecting in Express with a Master / Detail Page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am learning Node.js. I am in the process of building a basic app for the sake of learning. At this time, I'm trying to do a master/detail page. Here is the master page.

**/views/master.ejs**

```
<html>
  <body>
    [items would go here]
    <a href="/new">add new</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

The user will see this page when they visit '/'. When they click the "add new" link, I will take them to "/new". The code for the view is here:

**/views/detail.ejs**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm" method="post" action="/new">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have these successfully working. However, when a user clicks submit, I'm not sure how to redirect them back to the "/" view. At this time, my routing code looks like this:

```
var router = require('express').Router();

/* GET the master page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('master', { });
});

/* GET the new page */
router.get('/new', function(req, res) {
    res.render('detail', { });
});

/* POST new item */
router.post('/new', function(req, res) {
    console.log('creating item...');

    // The following line just shows "undefined" in the browser"
    // I don't know if 1) Its correct or 2) If I should do it some other way
    res.redirect(200, '/', { }); 
});
```

How do I handle loading views in a master-detail page scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of express are you using? I don't think that `redirect` takes a 3rd argument http://expressjs.com/api.html

Comment: @azium I'm using 4.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried redirecting without passing a view model? For example:

```
res.redirect('/projects/setup/website/details');
```

None of the samples in the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.redirect) show a view model being passed.

Comment: Ah ha! I should pay closer attention to the docs. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to redirect in a POST. If you would like to render the home page after your POST request, simply render the expected result.

```
/* POST new item */
router.post('/new', function(req, res) {
    // do server stuff ...

    res.render('master'); 
});
```

Comment: After a user clicks the "submit" button, I want them the "master" view to load. In addition, the URL in the address bar of their browser should be "/". From what I can tell, the approach you show won't do the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I think use below code may helpful.

```
router.post('/new', function(req, res) {
console.log('creating item...');
res.redirect('/');   // if you don`t specify status defaults to 302 found
});
```

see this link : http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.redirect

Comment: No luck. I keep getting a "404" error. Oddly, its appending "200" In the console window, I see: `GET /200 404 3.453 ms - 90` I have no idea where that 200 is coming from.